# How to render multiple checkboxes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React and trying to work with Form components. I am trying to render a very simple form with 3 checkboxes but i am having some trouble trying to make it work. I am fairly inexperienced with React and React forms so any help will be appreciated.

Please check out this working [fiddle] (https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dust-gbjox?file=/src/App.js).

This is the snippet of code below:-

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkboxes: [
      { name: "Check 1", value: false },
      { name: "Check 2", value: false },
      { name: "Check 3", value: false }
    ]
  };

  renderCheckboxes = () => {
    this.state.checkboxes.map((cb, i) => (
      <label>
        {cb.name}
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </label>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderCheckboxes()}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thank you for all the help and feedback. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: you aren't returning anything from `renderCheckboxes`

Comment: @DanielA.White Whoops!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return from renderCheckBoxes

```
renderCheckboxes = () => {
return this.state.checkboxes.map((cb, i) => (
  <label>
    {cb.name}
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </label>
));
```

};

Comment: Whoops!!! Thank you for the help. Accepting as soon as the timer ends.